# Strip Wordpress Shortcode from Content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using Wordpress shortcodes.

I also want to use a Front End Plugin and also have a popup that shows content from a post.

The problem is both would show the shortcode insertion code in the text area.

How could I hide the code but still enable them to work as usual. Is there a plugin or do I have to get down and dirty with code?

> [su_custom_gallery source="media: 963,965,966,967" link="lightbox" width="160" height="106" title="never"] [intense_heading font_color="#000000" font_weight="700" tag="h4"]DOLAN's HEATING & PLUMBING CONTRACTORS[/intense_heading] Welcome to Dolan's Heating and Plumbing

Comment: Where are you using this code in? Widget or some page? Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-modal/ for popups

Comment: Thanks for that Felix.....it is part of a Theme and the problem is actually with a popup which shows info... http://localbusinesslink.ie/mapsearch/ ...click a Business on the map and then "Brief" and you will see shortcodes...

Comment: Ok, I understand. You / theme code adds it in visual and just takes literally every code you put in it. It doesnt understand wordpress shortcodes. So, either create page - put gallery - inspect it - copy html code or use your own gallery.
See if you can add it some other way